# Word for unconscious body movements

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word for unconscious movements such as stroking chin while deep in thought or bouncing a knee when bored?  Possibilities that don't quite fit are body language, affectations, tics, tells, gestures.

> You could tell Fred was deep in thought because he was tapping his temple with his finger.  He always displays this _______ when lost in thought.

Comment: A comment, because I both prefer *tic* and cannot vouch for using *fidget* as a noun, but perhaps *fidgeting* would fill the blank here.

Comment: Great ideas, all.  "Mannerism" is exactly what I had in mind.
"(particular) fidget" mentioned below is also accurate, but not as elegant 
Thanks!
(now how do I credit @alwayslearning - maybe I don't have the rep to do so?)

Comment: @Jeff You give credit by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/220651). IIRC, even 1 rep users have the ability to do so. But, please accept the answer you feel is best, not simply the first one!

Comment: To recap: (unconsciously or not) Bouncing your knees is a *tic*. Stroking your chin is a *mannerism*. Both could be labeled as *fidgeting*. But none of those words is needed to write that sentence. *You can always tell when Fred is deep in thought because he'll keep tapping his temple with his finger.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are referring to ***mannerisms***.

> "You could tell Fred was deep in thought because he was tapping his
>   temple with his finger. He always displays this ***mannerism*** when lost in
>   thought."

M-W:

> **[mannerism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mannerism)** 
>   *noun*
>
> 2 :  a characteristic and often unconscious mode or peculiarity of
>   action, bearing, or treatment
>
> The actor can mimic the President's mannerisms perfectly.
>   'quirky mannerisms such as toying with her hair and tapping her toes'

Comment: Yes. In the current context, 'mannerism' is an apt choice.

Answer (score 34):

That is called a *[tic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic)*, or sometimes expanded to *nervous tic.*  As described in the wikipedia link, a tic is a sudden, repetitive movement or sound that some people make, which can be difficult to control.

Note the spelling with no k, a tick with a k is an arachnid.

Comment: Given the examples the OP gave though, I don't think he was refering to 
tics. A tic is difficult to stop even when you're looking at yourself doing 
it, and it's tipically limited to muscle twitching (when refering to 
movement not sound). It wouldn't include something like "stroking chin", and "bouncing knee when bored" sounds like it's done semiconsciously for entertainment rather than because the leg is moving on its own.

Comment: @jlmg "Tics may increase as a result of stress, fatigue, boredom, or high-energy emotions, which can include negative emotions, such as anxiety, as well as positive emotions, such as excitement or anticipation." –Wiki. "or bouncing a knee when bored" –OP

Comment: @jlmg - My son has Tourette Syndrome, a tic disorder.  Almost anything is fodder to become a tic.

Comment: @cobaltduck - Small note: tics are often repetitive but they need not be.

Comment: I disagree. Tics are unvoluntary movements, like twitches. Things like stroking your chin, that are just done (semi-)subconciously, are not tics.

Comment: @poepje: I don’t know about in technical medical usage, but in everyday speech, habitual subconscious actions like chin-stroking, head-scratching etc certainly get commonly referred to as tics.

Comment: @PLL Okay, I wasn't familiair with that usage. That's new to me..

Comment: @PLL And what you said holds in technical medical usage, too.

Answer (score 17):

I would call this ***fidgeting***.

> **Fidg·et** / ˈfijit/
>   • v. (**fidg·et·ed**, **fidg·et·ing** ) [intr.] make small
>   movements, esp. of the hands and feet, through nervousness or
>   impatience: *the audience had begun to **fidget** on their chairs*.
>
> • n. a
>   quick, small movement, typically a repeated one, caused by nervousness
>   or impatience: he disturbed other people with convulsive **fidgets**.
>
> - a person given to such movements, esp. one whom other people find
>     irritating.
> - (usu. **fidgets**) a state of mental or physical
>     restlessness or uneasiness: *a marketing person full of nervous energy
>     and **fidgets***.
>
> DERIVATIVES: **fidg·et·er** n. **fidg·et·y** adj.

—["fidget." *The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English*, via *Encyclopedia.com*. 12 Dec. 2016.](http://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/fidget-0)

In your sentence,

> You could tell Fred was deep in thought because he was tapping his
>   temple with his finger. He always displays this **fidgeting** when
>   lost in thought.

Or

> You could tell Fred was deep in thought because he was tapping his
>   temple with his finger. He always displays this **(particular)
>   fidget** when lost in thought.

---

Examples of **fidgeting** used for this:

> A new study finds that **fidgeting** — the toe-tapping, foot-wagging
>   and other body movements that annoy your co-workers — is in fact good
>   for your health. —[Gretchen Reynolds, "Why Fidgeting is Good
>   Medicine", *New York Times*, 9/14/2016.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/14/well/move/why-fidgeting-is-good-medicine.html)
>
> **Fidgeting** is making small movements with your body, usually your hands and feet. It’s associated with not paying attention.
>   **Fidgeting** often reflects discomfort and restlessness. For example, if you’ve been listening to a lecture for a long time, you may find
>   yourself tapping your pencil. —["What causes fidgeting?"
>   *Healthline.com*.](http://www.healthline.com/symptom/fidgeting)

And examples of usage of *fidget* on its own as a noun for this kind of action (definitely the less common of the two terms):

> Nicks started fiddling with the tassels streaming from her mike stand,
>   an annoying **fidget** that continued intermittently throughout the
>   show. —[Bill White, "Nicks still casts a musical spell", *Seattle
>   Post-Intelligencer*, 8/14/2001.](http://bla.fleetwoodmac.net/index.php?page=index_v2&id=384&c=11)
>
> *Tap tap tap tap*. Tim Caton taps his pencil on his desk in his hospitality management class. To classmates, it’s an annoying
>   **fidget**. But Caton heeds a different beat. —["Life by the Numbers", *Vox Magazine*, 10/11/2012.](http://archive.voxmagazine.com/stories/2012/10/11/life-numbers/)

---

Man, I'm slow! Just noticed that this was suggested in comments while I've been typing. Hat-tip to @stevesliva.

Comment: Per the dictionary Google uses, I was surprised to see *fidget* itself described as a noun for the mannerism and not the person.  I wouldn't call that "a fidget."   I'd call it "a tic."  That is why I was not leaning towards answering this way, but it is the #1 word for the action and not the mannerism.  And your quotes to support the use '[a] fidget' that I was leery of.

Comment: Somehow I don't think fidgeting is _unconscious_ - it's an active method of showing some kind of discomfort.

Answer (score 11):

"Tic" is a great suggestion because it precisely fits the definition. In the interests of variety, let me suggest another word which is a close fit: **twitch**.

> VERB
>
> Give or cause to give a short, sudden jerking or convulsive movement:
>
> - [no object] ‘her lips twitched and her eyelids fluttered’
> - [with object] ‘the dog twitched his ears’

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/twitch)

Another Dictionary actually includes involuntary movement in the definition.

> to make a sudden small movement with a part of the body, usually without intending to.
>
> - He tried to suppress a smile but felt the corner of his mouth twitch.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twitch)

Answer (score 5):

What you may be thinking of is a **Thinking Tic**, which is a specific type of [Tic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tic)

> #### Thinking Tic
>
> *Examples:*
>
> - Twirling your fingers and pen, sometimes biting it in annoyance.
> - Stroking your chin or scratching your beard in wonder.
> - Drumming your fingers while staring absent-mindedly.
> - Clicking your tongue impatiently.

([TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThinkingTic))

Answer (score 5):

In psychology, it is called [*unconscious behavior*](https://generalpsychology.wordpress.com/tag/unconscious-behavior/):

> any behavior that the person is not aware of (ex. mannerisms, shaking of the legs while sitting, biting your fingers, playing with your pen while listening to your teacher’s discussion, etc.)

[GeneralPsychology.com]

Comment: Plus one for *behavior* (note, that is the first and foremost tag for the linked article), as it was only though *learned behavior* that I'm now well aware of when I shake my legs and that I have an "annoying habit of wiggling". And for most directly answering the title, as IMO the OP's dualistic context leaves us having to look for a hypernym (of basically every answer on this page).

Answer (score 4):

Such behavior can also be called a **[habit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/habit)**, which means a behavior or simple pattern of behaviors which is done frequently and without consciously thinking about it.

"He had the annoying habit of wiggling his shoe while concentrating, causing the shoelace to make a tapping sound which drove the other students nuts."

Comment: I think this is closest to what OP describes, particularly if you qualify it as a *nervous habit* or *restless habit*.

Comment: Yes, "Nervous habit" fits nicely

Answer (score 3):

**idiosyncrasy** [id-ee-uh-sing-kruh-see] noun

> 1. A structural or behavioral trait peculiar to an individual or a group.
> 2. A physiological or temperamental peculiarity.
>
> <sub>The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiosyncrasy)</sub>

---

> a mode of behavior or way of thought peculiar to an individual. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=idiosyncrasy%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

---

> An idiosyncrasy is an unusual feature of a person (though there are also other uses, see below). It also means odd habit. The term is often used to express eccentricity or peculiarity. A synonym may be "quirk".
>
> The term "idiosyncrasy" originates from Greek ἰδιοσυγκρασία *idiosynkrasía*, "a peculiar temperament, habit of body" (from ἴδιος *idios*, "one's own", σύν *syn*, "with" and κρᾶσις *krasis*, "mixture").
>
> In psychoanalysis and behaviorism, it is used for the personal way a given individual reacts, perceives and experiences a common situation: a certain dish made of meat may cause nostalgic memories in one person and disgust in another. These reactions are called **idiosyncratic**. –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiosyncrasy)

*You could tell Fred was deep in thought because he was tapping his temple with his finger. He always displays this* [idiosyncrasy]* *when lost in thought.*

*See also, ***behavior***, ***eccentricity***, ***peculiarity***, ***quirk***, ***reaction***, ***tendency*** and ***odd habit***.

Answer (score 2):

*Tic* fits well, but if you want to emphasize that the behavior involuntarily reveals something about the person's mental state or thoughts, you could use [tell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell#Noun):

> A reflexive, often habitual behavior, especially one occurring in a
>   context that often features attempts at deception by persons under
>   psychological stress (such as a poker game or police interrogation),
>   that reveals information that the person exhibiting the behavior is
>   attempting to withhold.

Comment: As a poke rplayer, this is the word than sprang to my mind. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_%28poker%29 and http://www.pokerology.com/lessons/poker-tells/ etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Could be

**spasm**
*is a sudden involuntary contraction of a muscle, a group of muscles, or a hollow organ such as the heart.*

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spasm

Comment: "bouncing a knee when bored" is hardly a spasm.

Answer (score 0):

Adventitial movements is used to describe involuntary movements that lack consistent patterns like tics, tremor or myoclonic jerks, but are not severe enough to be choreiform (i.e., dance like).  Figet describes the same pattern of movements